Why does my function return NULL instead of a value?
As an exercise, I need to calculate a commission value based on the sales made by the employees on that month. Problem is, the employee with ID 3 didn't sell anything, so there a NULL value to them.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_COMISION_EMP(rut empleado.rut_empleado%TYPE) 
RETURN NUMBER IS 
    valor_comision factura.monto_total%TYPE := 0;

BEGIN

    SELECT NVL(ROUND(SUM(monto_total) * 0.183), 0)
    INTO valor_comision
    FROM factura
    WHERE rut_empleado = rut
    GROUP BY rut_empleado;
    
    RETURN valor_comision;

END fn_comision_emp;

I get the ID from the employee (rut_empleado) using a SELECT statement.
SELECT 
    rut_empleado,
    fn_comision_emp(rut_empleado) Comisión
FROM
    empleado;

The table, Factura, only has 4 rows, three by employee 1, and one by employee 2. monto_total is the values from the sales.
When I run the SELECT statement, I get this result:
RUT_EMPLEADO   COMISIÓN
------------ ----------
     1111111     199919
     2222222     102114
     3333333           

It should look like this:
RUT_EMPLEADO   COMISIÓN
------------ ----------
     1111111     199919
     2222222     102114
     3333333          0

Why is that? I tried using exceptions (WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN) and IF's to try to fix it, but it still shows NULL value.

It might be helpful to include how you tried to fix this with NO_DATA_FOUND, as that can work; but we can't tell you what you wrong with your attempt at that.

Why GROUP BY rut_empleado? You only select data for one rut_empleado (WHERE rut_empleado = rut), so remove the GROUP BY clause. Thus you won't dismiss the row for  3333333, and your NVL will work.

You where right Thorsten Kettner. It didn't need that GROUP BY clause. I used it because I thought it would've been necessary given that in Factura table they're multiple values for and single ID. I was wrong, thank you for insight!

The problem is being caused by the group by. Because you have included that your query returns no rows for employee 3333333, as there is no rut_rempleado value found in that table to use for the grouping. The NO_DATA_FOUND exception is being thrown; but when you call a function from SQL you can’t see that as it is silently ignored.  
You mentioned catching the exception, and that would work:
create or replace FUNCTION FN_COMISION_EMP(rut empleado.rut_empleado%TYPE) 
RETURN NUMBER IS 
    valor_comision factura.monto_total%TYPE := 0;

BEGIN

    SELECT NVL(ROUND(SUM(monto_total) * 0.183), 0)
    INTO valor_comision
    FROM factura
    WHERE rut_empleado = rut
    GROUP BY rut_empleado;
    
    RETURN valor_comision;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RETURN 0;
END fn_comision_emp;
/




RUT_EMPLEADO
COMISIÓN




1111111
199919


2222222
102114


3333333
0



(You probably don’t need the NVL() in this version - only if you have rows in the table where monto_total is null, which make the SUM() result also null; but in that case you probably want to apply the NVL() to the column, not the SUM()…)
In this case you are searching for a single value, rut, so you don’t actually need the group-by clause here; if you remove it then it doesn’t try and fail so no exception handler is needed either:
create or replace FUNCTION FN_COMISION_EMP(rut empleado.rut_empleado%TYPE) 
RETURN NUMBER IS 
    valor_comision factura.monto_total%TYPE := 0;

BEGIN

    SELECT NVL(ROUND(SUM(monto_total) * 0.183), 0)
    INTO valor_comision
    FROM factura
    WHERE rut_empleado = rut;
    
    RETURN valor_comision;

END fn_comision_emp;
/




RUT_EMPLEADO
COMISIÓN




1111111
199919


2222222
102114


3333333
0



You can see that the query returns null with the group-by clause and zero without it if you run just that query on its own, with a fixed value - I've included that in the fiddle.
Presumably the exercise is specifically to do this with a function, but yout don’t need one; you can get the same result with an outer join:
SELECT
    e.rut_empleado,
    NVL(ROUND(SUM(f.monto_total) * 0.183), 0) Comisión
FROM
    empleado e
LEFT JOIN
    factura f
ON
    f.rut_empleado = e.rut_empleado
GROUP BY e.rut_empleado;




RUT_EMPLEADO
COMISIÓN




1111111
199919


2222222
102114


3333333
0



fiddle

Thank you so much. The exception you used worked for me perfectly. When I tried to used that same exception, I wrote it like this: WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN valor_comision := 0; so, that was the error I think.
